# Weekday picker for Angular 2/4/5

Tags: angular, datepicker

I've been searching for a weekday picker, that allows to choose only the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc) without showing exact days of the month. But I haven't found any of those, only default datepickers with dates, years and other common stuff.

Maybe someone has already found such a weekday picker? Would be glad for help. If not, I guess the easiest way is to build one from scratch.

I found only similar picker for angularJS. Here's what I mean -

```
`https://codepen.io/jasesmith/pen/reLEyb`
```

Comment: I have a workable example of this using angular's material design, however the component should be portable regardless. Would you like me to put the stackblitz here?

Comment: How about a simple select box?

Comment: @Questioning would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've currently got [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/days-of-the-week-chips) example that uses material-design chips, though the logic is portable.

I didn't bother putting the tests in here since I don't know how to run them from stackblitz. However if you want to use this code take a look at `app.component.html` and `app.component.ts`.

The `selectable-chips.component` isn't really named abstractly enough. It takes in some default `chips`, which it uses to create the chips list and it also takes in `initialChips` if you want to pre-select some chips.

It will raise an event you can hook into, example in `app.component.ts` (this one just `console.logs`) to get the information you want.

Hope this helps.